# What arguments are available for the mobileiron URI scheme on iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, mobile-device-management

This concerns the MobileIron MyPhone@Work Client, I noticed a `mobileiron://` URI scheme is available on iOS.

I was thinking of using this with a webclip, that directs a user to the right server for registering on the MDM server. (now I'm getting ahead of myself)

Now I'm curious what arguments are available.

Comment: I believe this question is a bit too localized for this site.

Comment: "Ask Different" is a terrible title for this site then.

Comment: Maybe MobileIron has some support channels or a community where such questions would be better suited?

Comment: Sure, right before asking my question here, I opened a ticket with them.

Comment: The URI scheme isn't mentioned in their knowledge base or guides, so I figured I might post it here, as this site has questions on MDM as well.

Answer (score 1):

The scheme is an open one. Apps register with iOS when they get installed, and if there is no app to take an arbitrary://link then it will just fail or go to mobile Safari.

I believe Apple maintains a list of helper prefixes, but doesn't publish it.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the outcome if more than one app on the device tries to register the same URL schema is undefined.

Excerpt from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW10):

> Note: If more than one third-party app registers to handle the same
>   URL scheme, there is currently no process for determining which app
>   will be given that scheme.